# BigQuery/SQL: Filling in gaps as duplicate rows between years

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have a very similar scenario as shown in this thread: [Duplicate groups of records to fill multiple date gaps in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097764/duplicate-groups-of-records-to-fill-multiple-date-gaps-in-google-bigquery)

The query I'm using is as follows:

```
WITH history AS (
  SELECT 2012 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 10 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2010 AS d, 'b' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 15 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2014 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'y' AS partner, 11 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2012 AS d, 'b' AS product, 'y' AS partner, 16 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2015 AS d, 'b' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 13 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2017 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'y' AS partner, 15 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2017 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 15 AS value 
),
daterange AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fiscalYear) as date_in_range
  FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2010-01-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ) AS fiscalYear),
temp AS (
  SELECT d, product, partner, value, LEAD(d) OVER(PARTITION BY product, partner ORDER BY d) AS next_d
  FROM history
  ORDER BY product, partner, d
)
SELECT date_in_range, product, partner, value
FROM daterange
JOIN temp
ON daterange.date_in_range >= temp.d 
AND (daterange.date_in_range < temp.next_d OR temp.next_d IS NULL)
ORDER BY product, partner, date_in_range
```

One thing I noticed, which isn't ideal for my scenario is that the dates for each product, partner combination don't always start at 2010 which is what I want.

So the output for each product-partner should have date_in_range [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]

The output this query returns is:

```
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| date_in_range | product | partner | value |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | a       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | a       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | a       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | a       | y       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | a       | y       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | a       | y       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2010          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2011          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
```

The desired output is:

```
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| date_in_range | product | partner | value |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2010          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2011          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | a       | x       | 10    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | a       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | a       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | a       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2010          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2011          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | a       | y       | 11    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | a       | y       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | a       | y       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | a       | y       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2010          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2011          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | b       | x       | 15    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | b       | x       | 13    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2010          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2011          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2012          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2013          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2014          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2015          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2018          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2019          | b       | y       | 16    |
+---------------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I find it really hard to decipher what your question really is.

Comment: The sample data is embedded in the query

Comment: You will need to change your `join` (which is an `inner join`) to a `left join` in order to pull in all years from the `daterange` CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH history AS (
  SELECT 2012 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 10 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2010 AS d, 'b' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 15 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2014 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'y' AS partner, 11 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2012 AS d, 'b' AS product, 'y' AS partner, 16 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2015 AS d, 'b' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 13 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2017 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'y' AS partner, 15 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2017 AS d, 'a' AS product, 'x' AS partner, 15 AS value 
),
daterange AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fiscalYear) AS date_in_range
  FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2010-01-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ) AS fiscalYear),
history_ext AS (
  SELECT date_in_range, x.product, x.partner, value
  FROM daterange dr
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT product, partner FROM history) x
  LEFT JOIN history h
  ON dr.date_in_range = h.d
  AND STRUCT(h.product, h.partner) = STRUCT(x.product, x.partner)
)
SELECT date_in_range, product, partner, 
COALESCE(
  value, 
  LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY product, partner ORDER BY date_in_range ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
  FIRST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY product, partner ORDER BY date_in_range ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
) AS value
FROM history_ext
ORDER BY product, partner, date_in_range
```

and returns

```
Row date_in_range   product partner value    
1   2010    a   x   10   
2   2011    a   x   10   
3   2012    a   x   10   
4   2013    a   x   10   
5   2014    a   x   10   
6   2015    a   x   10   
7   2016    a   x   10   
8   2017    a   x   15   
9   2018    a   x   15   
10  2019    a   x   15   
11  2010    a   y   11   
12  2011    a   y   11   
13  2012    a   y   11   
14  2013    a   y   11   
15  2014    a   y   11   
16  2015    a   y   11   
17  2016    a   y   11   
18  2017    a   y   15   
19  2018    a   y   15   
20  2019    a   y   15   
21  2010    b   x   15   
22  2011    b   x   15   
23  2012    b   x   15   
24  2013    b   x   15   
25  2014    b   x   15   
26  2015    b   x   13   
27  2016    b   x   13   
28  2017    b   x   13   
29  2018    b   x   13   
30  2019    b   x   13   
31  2010    b   y   16   
32  2011    b   y   16   
33  2012    b   y   16   
34  2013    b   y   16   
35  2014    b   y   16   
36  2015    b   y   16   
37  2016    b   y   16   
38  2017    b   y   16   
39  2018    b   y   16   
40  2019    b   y   16
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mikhail