# BigQuery SQL : Decrease remaining minutes counter in successive rows calculation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, popsql

I have some logs with dates and an aggregated `minutes` counter time.

Each hours (a row) had been filled out with a trick like this one : [Duplicate groups of records to fill multiple date gaps in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097764/duplicate-groups-of-records-to-fill-multiple-date-gaps-in-google-bigquery)

The issue :

I want to complete `time` column with `minutes` still available (understand here, 60 minutes maximum per hour)

Here's the desired output :
`remainingTime` is resulting from previous rows.. Let's say `remainingTime` = 70 minutes

```
#standardSQL
WITH history AS (
  SELECT '2017-01-01' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-02' AS date, 'a' AS product, 100 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-03' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-04' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-05' AS date, 'a' AS product, 30 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-06' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-01' AS date, 'b' AS product, 100 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-02' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-03' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-04' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-05' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes
```

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| product |    date    | minutes | remainingTime |       time          |
+---------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|    a    | 2017-01-01 |   0     |  10           | 60 (max 60 reached) | // 0 + 70 - 60 = 10
|    a    | 2017-01-02 |   100   |  50           | 60 (same)           | // 100 + 10 - 60 = 50
|    a    | 2017-01-03 |   0     |  0            | 50 (only 50/60)     | // 0 + 50 - 50 = 0            
|    a    | 2017-01-04 |   0     |  0            | 0 (and so on)       | // 0 + 0 - 0 = 0
|    a    | 2017-01-05 |   30    |  0            | 30                  | // 30 + 0 - 30 = 0
|    a    | 2017-01-06 |   0     |  0            | 0                   | // 0 + 0 - 0 = 0
 

... and so on for other products
+---------------+--------+------+
```

I'm almost done with a complex and ugly query but I'm currently stuck with a temporary calculation column..

(PS : I didn't practice SQL for many years, so I'm learning back again fundamentals and discovering BigQuery Standard SQL in the same time)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does not support recursive operations natively. Try `array_agg()` combined with [JavaScript user-defined function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure), but this approach is not very scalable:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION special_sum(x ARRAY<INT64>)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  var remaining = 70;
  var time = 0;
  for (const num of x)
  {
     time = Math.min(parseInt(num) + remaining, 60);
     remaining = parseInt(num) + remaining - time;
  }
  return time;
""";

WITH history AS (
  SELECT '2017-01-01' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-02' AS date, 'a' AS product, 100 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-03' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-04' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-05' AS date, 'a' AS product, 30 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-06' AS date, 'a' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-01' AS date, 'b' AS product, 100 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-02' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-03' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-04' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-05' AS date, 'b' AS product, 0 AS minutes 
)
select *, 
 special_sum(array_agg(minutes) over (partition by product order by date rows unbounded preceding)) as time 
from history
```

[image]

Comment: TY Sergey !
I upvote your solution because it's working pretty well ! 
It looks very interesting..
I keep on looking for a "smartest" way to achieve this