# Google BigQuery SQL: How to fill in gaps in a table with dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Data Table**:

| Dates | Customer | Subscription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/02/2020 | A | free |
| 21/02/2020 | A | free |
| 22/02/2020 | A | free |
| 23/02/2020 | B | free |
| 23/03/2020 | A | full |
| 01/03/2020 | B | full |
| 01/03/2020 | A | full |
| 02/03/2020 | A | full |

Need to fill gaps in dates by the value in the previous date

**Output**:

| Dates | Customer | Last Subscription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/02/2020 | A | free |
| 21/02/2020 | A | free |
| 22/02/2020 | A | free |
| 23/03/2020 | A | full |
| 23/03/2020 | B | free |
| 24/02/2020 | A | full |
| 24/02/2020 | B | free |
| 25/02/2020 | A | full |
| 25/02/2020 | B | free |
| 26/02/2020 | A | full |
| 26/02/2020 | B | free |
| 27/02/2020 | A | full |
| 27/02/2020 | B | free |
| 28/02/2020 | A | full |
| 28/02/2020 | B | free |
| 01/03/2020 | A | full |
| 01/03/2020 | B | full |
| 02/03/2020 | A | full |
| 02/03/2020 | B | full |

I found a similar solution [Duplicate groups of records to fill multiple date gaps in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097764/duplicate-groups-of-records-to-fill-multiple-date-gaps-in-google-bigquery), but it is not suitable because in my example each `Customer` has a different start date.

Comment: what the data type of `Dates` column? is it date or string?

Comment: the data type is Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below

```
with temp as (
  select customer, dates from (    
    select customer, min(dates) min_date, max(dates) max_date
    from `project.dataset.table`
    group by customer
  ), unnest(generate_date_array(min_date, max_date)) dates
)
select customer, dates, 
  first_value(subscription ignore nulls) over win as subscription
from temp a
left join `project.dataset.table` b
using(customer, dates)
window win as (partition by customer order by dates desc rows between current row and unbounded following)
# order by dates, customer
```

If to apply to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend approach this using `lead()` like this:

```
with data as (
      select cast('2020-02-20' as date) as dates, 'A' as customer, 'free' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-02-21' as date) as dates, 'A' as customer, 'free' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-02-22' as date) as dates, 'A' as customer, 'free' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-02-23' as date) as dates, 'B' as customer, 'free' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-03-23' as date) as dates, 'A' as customer, 'full' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-03-01' as date) as dates, 'B' as customer, 'full' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-03-01' as date) as dates, 'A' as customer, 'full' as subscription union all
      select cast('2020-03-02' as date) as dates, 'A' as customer, 'full' as subscription 
)
select d.customer, dy, d.subscription
from (select d.*,
             lead(dates) over (partition by customer order by dates) as next_date
      from data d
     ) d cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(d.dates, coalesce(date_add(d.next_date, interval -1 day), d.dates), interval 1 day)) dy;
```

The reason that I recommend this is because the `unnest()` occurs *within a single row*, so the is no data movement for matching dates.  In addition no window function is needed to fill in `subscription`.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery recently introduced `GAP_FILL` function that can be used to do this ([see GAP_FILL BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time-series-functions#gap_fill)).

The query will look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM GAP_FILL(
  TABLE data,  -- input table to gap fill
  'dates',  -- time column name
  INTERVAL 1 DAY,
  partitioning_columns => ['customer'],
  value_columns => [
    ('subscription', 'locf')  -- fill with the last observation
  ]
);
```