# SQL (bigquery) Repeat values from previous day if they don't exist already

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table that includes users that created an event in the app and they produced some revenue based on this event (it's added cummulatively every day):

| date | user_id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | A | 0.5 |
| 2022-04-01 | B | 0.3 |
| 2022-04-01 | C | 0.7 |
| 2022-04-02 | B | 0.6 |
| 2022-04-02 | C | 0.9 |
| 2022-04-03 | C | 1.2 |

What I want to do is use the data about all the users from the first day, but if they don't bring any revenue, I would like to use the revenue value for this user from the previous day, like so:

| date | user_id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | A | 0.5 |
| 2022-04-01 | B | 0.3 |
| 2022-04-01 | C | 0.7 |
| 2022-04-02 | A | 0.5 |
| 2022-04-02 | B | 0.6 |
| 2022-04-02 | C | 0.9 |
| 2022-04-03 | A | 0.5 |
| 2022-04-03 | B | 0.6 |
| 2022-04-03 | C | 1.2 |

My initial idea was to somehow copy first day user_id's and leave the revenue value for this day as null:

| date | user_id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | A | 0.5 |
| 2022-04-01 | B | 0.3 |
| 2022-04-01 | C | 0.7 |
| 2022-04-02 | A | null |
| 2022-04-02 | B | 0.6 |
| 2022-04-02 | C | 0.9 |
| 2022-04-03 | A | null |
| 2022-04-03 | B | null |
| 2022-04-03 | C | 1.2 |

Then I would use this to find the right values to fill NULLs with

```
SELECT date, 
       user_id, 
       revenue, 
       LAST_VALUE(revenue, IGNORE NULLS) as last_values
FROM table
```

So the question is, how do I go about "copying" my first day users to every following day in the table?
Maybe, there is a better solution than the one I've thought about?

Comment: you need a left join of a time series, look for `time gap bigquery`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google BigQuery SQL: How to fill in gaps in a table with dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214846/google-bigquery-sql-how-to-fill-in-gaps-in-a-table-with-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of this task is generating an output that contains the cartesian product of "*user_id*" values with "*date*" values. One option is to generate the empty cartesian product first, then `LEFT JOIN` with your original table and fill the NULL values using a window function.

Instead of the `LAST_VALUE` function, you could use the `MAX` window function and limit its frame till the current row. Given that your revenue values are cumulative, you should get exactly the last non-null value as a correct output.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT date    FROM tab) dates
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tab) users 
            ON 1=1
)
SELECT cte.user_id,
       cte.date,
       COALESCE(tab.revenue, 
                MAX(revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
                                  ORDER     BY date   
                                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)) AS revenue
FROM      cte
LEFT JOIN tab 
       ON cte.user_id = tab.user_id
      AND cte.date    = tab.date
ORDER BY cte.user_id,
         cte.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select date, user_id, 
  first_value(revenue ignore nulls) over prev_values as revenue
from (select distinct date from your_table),
  (select distinct user_id from your_table)
left join your_table
using(date, user_id)
window prev_values as (
  partition by user_id order by date desc 
  rows between current row and unbounded following
)
order by date, user_id
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]